# Read from multiple similar unknown databases

Tags: c#, database, multiple-databases

I am new to coding in C#, most of my experience is in plain old C.

I am trying to code an application in C# that will look up information from one of many Access databases. Each database is similar in that they have the same tables (named appropriate to the database itself(PIC, PICenum, etc)). The same table in each database contains the same field names (LnetVar, Description, etc). Each database applies to a different data set, which is different from the other databases, which is why I have multiple databases instead of one all encompassing database. It also makes maintaining it much easier.

I currently have code that can access one specific database and pull out the data I need for use elsewhere in the code.

```
class DB_Handler
{
    lsftTestDataSet.PICDataTable ds;

    public DB_Handler(lsftTestDataSet.PICDataTable ds)
    {
        this.ds = ds;
    }

    public string GetDescription(byte lnetVar)
    {
        foreach (lsftTestDataSet.PICRow currentRow in ds)
        {
            if (currentRow.LnetVar == lnetVar)
            {
                return currentRow.Description;
            }
        }

        return "";
    }
}
```

I don't want to do the old Copy-Paste-Modify trick so that it can interact with each database. Rather I want a single function to call that I send the database I want to use as well as the relevant record and field information. From that it searches the database and returns the stored data.

I found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7447295/optimize-query-on-unknown-database), but it was focused on optimizing, not on actually doing it. I was also unable to follow the code snippet given to modify it to use with my code.

Any help you can give me would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `Copy-Paste-Modify kludge` ftfy

Comment: Passing dataset on the constructor probably wont be a right thing to do in a class which is responsible for db access. A function in this class should just take the primary key value as a parameter and return a dataset based results returned by the database.

Answer (score 0):

As you said, what you need is a method/function receiving a parameter containing the connection string you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this :-

In Web.config or App.Config

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="DbConnnectionString" connectionString="server=myserver;database={MyDatabasePlaceHolder};Integrated Security=SSPI;"
</connectionStrings>
```

and then in code (also, need to add a reference of System.Configuration.dll)

```
using System.Configuration;
class DB_Handler
{
        string connectionString=string.Empty;
        public DB_Handler(string databaseName)
        {
           this.connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DbConnnectionString"].ConnectionString.Replace ("{MyDatabasePlaceHolder}", databaseName)
        }

        public GetData()  
        {
          // Make use of this.connectionString to fetch data
        }
}
```

Comment: I have made most of the changes you recommended, however it doesn't recognize ConfigurationManager as a valid entry. Have I missed an important step along the way?

Comment: Have you added the reference of  System.Configuration.dll to your project? You can right click on the project > Add reference > .NET Tab > Select System.Configuration.dll.

Comment: Sorry about the delay, I hadn't added the reference. Its popping up now. Thanks!

Comment: If this answers your question, please don't forget to mark this as one. :-)